# Count nodes with Specific Value

Tags: xml, perl

I have an xml of the format given below. I would like to get the number of `HintPath` under `Project/ItemGroup/Reference`. I also need to get the number of `Private` nodes under `Project/ItemGroup/Reference` with node text `False`. How can I do this with Perl Script?

```
 <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="IronPython, Version= ...">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\shared\IronPython-1.1\IronPython.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="log4net, Version= ...">
        <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
        <HintPath>..\binaries\log4net.dll</HintPath>
        <Private>False</Private>
     </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: your XML is not well formed, please take the time to check your data before you ask for help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a solution using XML::Twig. Any DOM module like XML::LibXML would also work in a very similar way.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $t= XML::Twig->new->parse( \*DATA);
foreach my $reference ($t->findnodes( '/Project/ItemGroup/Reference'))
  { print "HintPath count: ", $reference->children_count( 'HintPath'), "\n";
    my $private=  $reference->descendants( 'Private[text()="False"]');
    print "False Private count: $private\n";
  }

__DATA__
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="IronPython, Version= ...">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\shared\IronPython-1.1\IronPython.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="log4net, Version= ...">
        <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
        <HintPath>..\binaries\log4net.dll</HintPath>
        <Private>False</Private>
     </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use XML::Simple 'XMLin';

my $xml = XMLin( join( "\n", <DATA> ), ForceArray => [ 'Reference' ] );

foreach my $reference ( @{ $xml->{ItemGroup}{Reference} } )
{
    # count the HintPath and Private (where False) elements in $reference
}

__DATA__
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
         ToolsVersion="3.5">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="IronPython, Version= ...">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\shared\IronPython-1.1\IronPython.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="log4net, Version= ...">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\binaries\log4net.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```